# syslog tag for systemd dotnet service keeps changing between SyslogIdentifier and process name

Tags: systemd, syslog

I have a number of .NET Core applications running as systemd services on Ubuntu 18.04 (systemd 237). The unit files look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=my-service dotnet service

[Service]
Type=simple
SyslogIdentifier=my-service
User=myservice
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
WorkingDirectory=/home/myservice
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/myservice/My.Service.dll
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitBurst=10
StartLimitInterval=60

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

For most of them the syslog tag I see in /var/log/syslog is the SyslogIdentifier set above, as expected. However, for one service I still see messages with "dotnet" as the syslog tag, even though `$ systemctl show my-service |grep SyslogIdentifier` shows `SyslogIdentifier=my-service`, as expected.

When I check journalctl it seems to keep alternating between "my-service" and the executable name ("dotnet"):

```
$ journalctl -u my-service -o verbose |grep SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=dotnet
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=my-service
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=my-service
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=dotnet
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=my-service
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=my-service
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=dotnet
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=my-service
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=my-service
    ...
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?